# Open an emacs org-mode file from C++ source code and automatically create an item

Tags: c++, emacs, org-mode

I'm working on a C++ project. Suppose I have the following directory structure:

```
project/
project/src
```

And I have the following files:

```
project/ChangeLog
project/todo.org
project/src/foo.cpp
```

I can work on the C++ source code in `foo.cpp` and then add a line into the ChangeLog file just with `C-x 4 a` as [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Change-Log-Commands.html#Change-Log-Commands) describes.

How can I achieve that same kind of functionality with org-mode on the file `todo.org`. I would like to keep a to do list relative to the source code. So if in `foo.cpp` I need to finish a function `void Foo::bla()` I would like an entry to be added to `todo.org` that mentions this function and the file it resides in much like `C-x 4 a` does for ChangeLog.

I would also like to be able to have the backward link from the org file to the `foo.cpp` file in which the to-do task is.

Comment: You might find a better audience on the [org-mode mailing list](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-mailing-list.html).

Comment: Thanks @Nemo, I'll try there too, and will keep looking for an answer (and post here once I find it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While org-mode is documented extensively, I do find the online manual to be
very dense. Luckily, there are many good tutorials online, but it's sometimes
hard to find the answer to a specific problem.

I suggest reading the org-mode manual section on [Capture](http://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html#Capture). You'll need to do a
little setup and the specifics depend on what version of org-mode you have. (I
recommend using 7.x. If you're stuck on 6.x, none of the capture setup I
describe below will work.)

Here's a simple snippet from my emacs setup:

```
;;; capture mode

(setq org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "/capture.org"))
(define-key global-map "\C-cc" 'org-capture)

(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline org-default-notes-file "Tasks")
     "** TODO %?\n  %i\n  %a")
        ("j" "Journal" entry (file+headline "~/journal/journal.org" "Today")
     "** %?\nEntered on %U\n  %i\n  %a")))
```

Now I hit <kbd>C-c c</kbd> when I'm in my source file. Org-mode lets me select
a template ([t]odo or [j]ournal in the example above), and fills it in
including a link to the line I was on when I initiated the capture.

---

**Updated with info about Refiling**: If you have multiple projects and want to keep separate todo lists, you should also learn about [Refiling](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Refiling-notes). The simplest setup is to have `org-refile-targets` contain a list of your todo.org files. During the capture process, you can "refile" the task directly into any of your refile targets.

```
(setq org-refile-targets 
  '((nil :maxlevel . 2) 
    ("~/project/todo.org" :level . 1)))
```

There's a nice walkthrough of capture and refiling on [this page about org-mode](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html).